# How can I make multidimensional dynamically allocated arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

before you mark this as a duplicate please notice that I'm looking for a more general solution for arrays of arbitrary dimensions. I have read many posts here or in forums about making 2D or 3D arrays of integers but these are specific solutions for specific dimensions. I want a general solution for an array of any dimension.
First I need to have a type of intlist as defined below:

```
typedef struct{
   int l // length of the list
   int * e // pointer to the first element of the array
}intlist;
```

this actually fills the gap in C for treating arrays just as pointers. using this type I can pass arrays to functions without worrying about loosing the size. 
then in the next step I want to have a mdintlist as multidimensional dynamically allocated arrays. the type definition should be something like this:

```
typedef struct Mdintlist{
    intlist d // dimension of the array
    /* second part */
}mdintlist;
```

there are several options for the second part. on option is that to have a pointer towards a mdintlist of lower dimension like

```
struct Mdintlist * c;
```

the other options is to use void pointers:

```
void * c;
```

I don't know how to continue it from here.

P.S. one solution could be to allocate just one block of memory and then call the elements using a function. However I would like to call the elements in array form. something like tmpmdintlist.c[1][2][3]...

Hope I have explained clearly what I want.

**P.S.** This is an ancient post, but for those who may end up here some of my efforts can be seen in [the Cplus repo](https://github.com/Foadsf/Cplus).

Comment: tnx. I didn't know that. next time I will ask there.

Comment: You cannot make both `array[2][3]` and `array[2][3][4]` represent *numbers* in the same program. If `array[2][3][4]` is a number, then `array[2][3]` is an array or a pointer. You cannot make this depend on what `array` or some other variable contain. Type is a *static* property of an expression.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar I'm trying to find the answer, however I have some errors while compiling. should I ask the question here in stackoverflow or at softwareengineering.stackexchange ?

Comment: @Foad Stackoverflow (as the name suggest) is for people having errors. So yes, as long as you put some effort into your question, SO is the place to debug errors :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't! you can only use the function option in c, because there is no way to alter the language semantics. In c++ however you can overload the `[]` operator, and even though I would never do such an ugly thing (`x[1][2][3]` *is alread y ugly, if you continue adding "dimensions" it gets really ugly*), I think it would be possible.

Comment: well actually I am not sure if I succeed to explain what I need. I don't want to alter the language. the main problem I want to solve is that I loos size of the arrays inside the functions. I succeed to solve the issue for 1D arrays defining the intlist. but I don't know how to achieve that for multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you separate the pointers and the array lengths, you end up with much less code.

```
int *one_dem_array;
size_t one_dem_count[1];

int **two_dem_array;
size_t two_dem_count[2];

int ***three_dem_array;
size_t three_dem_count[3];
```

This way you can still use your preferred notation.

```
int num_at_pos = three_dem_array[4][2][3];
```

Comment: this is actually one step closer to what I want. except I have to define pointers for specific dimensions manually. it would be great if I could use void pointers and then cast them each time based on the dimension.

Comment: @Foad so you a program that can interpret arrays of *n* dimension?

Comment: Well at ANY moment in C where you have a variable of unknown type, you MUST use void pointers.

Comment: yes that's why I suggested them. however I just can't figure the exact form out. I know how to cast type for void pointers `voidptr=typeptr` and then later use the value stored there by `*(type *)voidptr`...

Comment: Well here's your issue: if you have variable `void *multi_dem_array` that has, let's say, `N` dimensions, then how are you suppose to know how many indexes to code? ie `multi_dem_array[index1][index2][...][indexN]`. Making your request impossible unfortunately.

Comment: I have that information I think. the first element of the struct is an array which specified the exact dimension of the multi dimensional array.